# /dev/sda2: clean, 300685/7299072 files, 8930801/29173760 blocks

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

problem on acer aspire one laptop when it is about to turn off the message / dev / sda2 appears: clean, 300685/7299072 files, 8930801/29173760 blocks
This causes the laptop cannot be turned off with the shutdown button in Ubuntu 18.04 version

how to solve something like that?

Comment: Do you usually use the button to power it off?

Comment: yes, i always use the power button to turn off my laptop.
is there a solution to solve that problem.?

Comment: Don't use the 'power' button, but give the system commands that cleanly shutdown. The message you are seeing is because a problem was detected with shutdown (unclean shutdown) & the `fsck` (or *file-system check*) is performed to check for errors caused by the power-outage or unclean shutdown.  If you don't want to use mouse, or command, I'd suggest SysRq command at minimum to safely turn off (ie. REISUO is still better than power-off).  As I read what you've said; it's a user-created issue, but maybe you've not described it well enough. Is there a reason you're turning your system off badly?

Comment: @guiverc you beat me to it lol

Comment: One way avoiding frequent hard shutdown like this is to reboot into LiveCD, open gparted, select the right disk, the right partition,  and run check errors in that partition (problematic blocks could be autofixed).

Comment: Try using the command sudo poweroff

Comment: how to apply sysrq command on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: sudo poweroff command -
it doesn't work well on my ubuntu

Comment: For magic SysRq, hold down Alt and the SysRq or print screen key and while holding them press each of the following keys in turn R E I S U O